# generating prime p and q, with alpha of element of order q

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm working on VSSS (Feldman) but I cannot understand the statement as follows:

[image]

I'm not good in reading mathematical statements (but working on it). Can anyone explain this in simple mathematics. Example will be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

This is what I got so far.
Given the following values: n=4, k=3, s=12, p=5, q=3, g=4
wherein n is no. of shares, k is threshold, s is the secret, p and q are prime, g is the generator

Using the polynomial function f(x) = 12 + 3x +2x^2.
then, f(2) = 68 mod q = 68 mod 3 = 2

Computing on commitment:
c1 = g^12 mod p = 4^12 mod 5 = 1
c2 = g^3 mod p = 4^3 mod 5 = 4
c3 = g^2 mod p = 4^2 mod 5 = 1
wherein, cx are commitments and 12,3 & 2 are coef
Verifying:

g^f(2) mod p = 4^2 mod 5 = **1**

c1^x^0 mod p = 1^2^0 mod 5 = 1
c2^x^1 mod p = 4^2^1 mod 5 = 4
c3^x^3 mod p = 1^2^2 mod 5 = 1
where x is the value of x in f(x) which is 2.

**1+4+1 <> 1** ????

What's wrong??? Am I doing it right?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: You should elaborate which part of that is confusing to you, and also give a bit of context. As it stands the question has no direct connection with cryptography at all.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Your example does not satisfy $q|(p-1)$, as $q=3$ is not a divisor of $p-1= 4$

Comment: Using your formula below, is q = 3, k = 4, p = 13 valid? Since p = kq + 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are generated the primes $p$ and $q$ such that $q | (p-1)$

What that means is that we search for two prime numbers $p$ and $q$, with the constraint that $q$ is a divisor of $p-1$.  That is, $kq = p-1$ for some integer $k$.

In practice, this is easy to do; we first pick a prime $q$ of an appropriate size, and then search for the value $k$ values of the appropriate size until we find a value $p = kq + 1$ which is also prime.

> and $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ ...

$\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ is the multiplicative group modulo $p$; its elements have an obvious identification to the between 1 and p that are relatively prime to $p$ (and since $p$ is prime, that means the values $[1, p-1]$), and

> an element of order $q$.

What this means is that the smallest positive value $\lambda$ for which $\alpha^\lambda \equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $\lambda = q$.

It turns out to be a lot easier to find such a value $\alpha$ than you'd expect; you pick an arbitrary value $\beta \in [2, p-2]$ and set $\alpha = \beta ^ {(p-1)/q} \pmod p$.  As long as $\beta \ne 1$, then $\alpha$ will have an order precisely $q$.

- We know that $\alpha^q = (\beta ^ {(p-1)/q})^q = \beta ^ {p-1} = 1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem (and because $p$ is prime)
- We know that $\alpha^r \ne 1$ for any $0 < r < q$, because if $\alpha^r = 1$, then we could show that $\alpha^{\gcd(q, r)} = 1$, and as $q$ is prime, $\gcd(q, r) = 1$, and so we'd have $\alpha^1 = 1$, which we had verified is not the case